# Ajax reading response from server as it gets sent

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to do some long polling and I'm having a hard time figuring out how I can read data from the server as it gets sent.

I have the following on the client:

```
var xhr = $.ajax('/getData');

setInterval(function(){
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
}, 1000); // reads response each 1s
```

The server

```
app.get('/getData', function(req, res){
  setInterval(function(){
    res.write('hi-' + Math.random()); // write random stuff each 1s
  }, 1000);
});
```

But `xhr.responseText` only gets populated when the request finishes.

Is this even possible to do? I have to make a new request for `/getData` every time I need something? I can't take advantages of the same request?

Comment: You can [chunk](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/streaming-chunked-html-node-js-data/) your response, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @BenFortune Thank you for the resource: "...some browsers that support chunked encoding in XHR still won’t let you access the data that’s received until the request is finished". It's a shame...

Answer (score 1):

Please read about onreadystatechange

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

```
$.ajax({
// ...
beforeSend: function (request, settings) {
    $(request).bind("readystatechange", function (e) { alert("changed " + e.target.readyState); });
}});
```

Comment: I'm aware of state changes, what I need is to read the response while the request is processing, not once it's processed. I'm guessing it's not possible....

Comment: sorry, i missunderstand - readystatechange give ability to process data as soon as it came to client - isn't that what you need? State 3 LOADING ; responseText holds partial data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to poll server multiple times or use a socket connection like [socket.io](http://socket.io/).
I reccomend reading [this article](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery).

Comment: Socket.io was my first attempt, but I couldn't get it working cross-browser. So it's really not possible without polling the server multiple times? Does node buffer the result or it's a client issue?

Comment: What isssues did you have with socket.io? It is designed for cross-browser compability, which browser was causing trouble?

Comment: Internet Explorer 8, I opened a issue, but still trying to solve it

Comment: As for other solutions quote from article about the topic: "Sadly, with our current technology, long polling cannot be accomplished with client-side JavaScript alone. What you really need is a framework that combines HTML5 WebSockets with some server-side component.". I'm 99% sure that nothing has changed in the js ajax calls since 2012 when it was written :/

Comment: Can you post the link to the socket.io issue?